# Can some tell me how to recover saved password from browser?

Tags: firefox, password-recovery

I am a **Mozilla Firefox** user and want to recover all my saved passwords as after formatting my Windows 7, all of the saved passwords are gone. Can someone please suggest me some hacks to do so?

**Thanks & regards**
**Sandra Diaz**

Comment: To clarify - "after formatting my Windows 7" - you mean you wiped the machine & installed a fresh Windows 7? If so, then you would need to have a backup to restore your data from.

Answer (score 0):

[This questionable site](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html) has a password recovery tool meant just for this, **but do not trust these programs**.  You have been warned.

Also, please only use for the use you asked about, not for anything *not things you shouldn't*.

Comment: Not really sure how that's going to help if it really was a nuke & pave - "after formatting my Windows 7" would indicate it was.

Comment: You can manually specify the library to scan for passwords.  Also, if it were nuked, then there'd be no hope at all, nor point for a question...

Comment: Yes as i have faced window corruption so i formatted my Windows and installed new windows , but as i am signed in in my Firefox so i am assuming that it will have some kind of backup of my passwords and different cache data. But i was wrong as all my saved browser cookies & cache memory is erased?

Comment: If you formatted the partition, then yes, the data is gone.